# Trying to emulate Icon property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I'm working on a (simple) user control that shows an image and a text and publish some of their properties.

```xaml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="defaultImg" 
                 UriSource="/mcWpfLibrary;component/Assets/TagBlue.png"/>
    <Thickness x:Key="defaultTxtMargin" 
                Left="5" Top="0" Right="0" Bottom="0"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
            Background="Transparent">
    <Image Width="{Binding Path=ImgWidth, ElementName=imageLabel, FallbackValue=24}"
           Height="{Binding Path=ImgWidth, ElementName=imageLabel, FallbackValue=24}"
           Source="{Binding Path=ImgSource, ElementName=imageLabel, FallbackValue={StaticResource defaultImg}}"
           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    />
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Text="{Binding Path=LabelText, ElementName=imageLabel, FallbackValue=Demo text}"
        FontSize="{Binding Path=LabelFontSize, ElementName=imageLabel, FallbackValue=22}"
        FontFamily="{Binding Path=LabelFontFamily, ElementName=imageLabel, FallbackValue=Segoe UI}"
        Foreground="{Binding Path=LabelForeground, ElementName=imageLabel, FallbackValue=White}"
        Margin="{Binding Path=LabelMargin, ElementName=imageLabel, FallbackValue={StaticResource defaultTxtMargin}}"
        Style="{Binding Path=LabelStyle, ElementName=imageLabel}"
        TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
        />
</StackPanel>
```

I'm trying to add an Icon property, similar to the Icon property of [AppBarButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbarbutton.icon?view=winrt-19041) control that allows to assign some stock images using a text instead an URI.

```c#
/// <summary>
/// Image Source property
/// </summary>
public ImageSource ImgSource
{
    get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ImgSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(LabelImg));

/// <summary>
/// Icon property
/// </summary>
public string Icon
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(IconProperty); }
    set 
    { 
        SetValue(IconProperty, value); 

        switch (value)
        {
            case "Document":
                ImgSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/mcWpfLibrary;component/Assets/AddDocumentBlue.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            case "Bullets":
                ImgSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/mcWpfLibrary;component/Assets/BulletsBlue.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;
            case "Tag":
                ImgSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/mcWpfLibrary;component/Assets/TagBlue.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;
        }
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(string), typeof(LabelImg), new PropertyMetadata(""));
```

It doesn't work if I assign some value using XAML:

```xaml
<jm:LabelImg x:Name="Btn"
             LabelText="hello world"
             Icon="Bullets"/>
```

But it properly works if I assign some value in the code-behind:

```c#
private void BtnDoc_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Btn.Icon = "Document";
}
```

Is there a way to use it in XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is how the dependency property is accessed in XAML and in code.

- The XAML processor does not use the `Icon` property at all, it directly accesses the `IconProperty` dependency property to get and set it.
- If you set the property in code, you call the setter of the `Icon` property, which is just a convenience wrapper around the dependency property, so you do not have to call `GetValue` and `SetValue` and it **should not be more than that** for the reason that you describe in your question, inconsistent behavior in XAML and code.

In order to solve the issue, you have to register a [*property changed callback*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.propertychangedcallback?view=net-5.0) in your dependency property declaration and move the code from the `Icon` property there. The callback will be invoked each time the property changes, so the behavior is the same for setting the `Icon` property or its dependency property.

```
/// <summary>
/// Icon property
/// </summary>
public string Icon
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(IconProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
}


public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", 
                                typeof(string), 
                                typeof(LabelImg),
                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIconChanged)));


private static void OnIconChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var labelImg = (LabelImg)d;
    var value = (string)e.NewValue;

    switch (value)
    {
        case "Document":
            labelImg.ImgSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/mcWpfLibrary;component/Assets/AddDocumentBlue.png", UriKind.Relative));
            break;
        case "Bullets":
            labelImg.ImgSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/mcWpfLibrary;component/Assets/BulletsBlue.png", UriKind.Relative));
            break;
        case "Tag":
            labelImg.ImgSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/mcWpfLibrary;component/Assets/TagBlue.png", UriKind.Relative));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the answer to fix some errors.

Comment: @McNets Thanks for editing, looks like I did not post the final version by accident.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your definition of the Icon dependency property.  You will need to define the PropertyChangedCallback in your PropertyMetadata.  Otherwise, it won't know what to do with the initial value that it receives from your XAML.

Quick Fix:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(OnPropertyChanged));

private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = d as <Insert-The-Name-Of-Your-UserControl>;
    control.Icon = e.NewValue as string;
}
```